# Jstree with Struts2

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am creating jstree from struts2. Tree is generated from JSON & JSON is created from Action class. I am also using a search plugin with tree. When I type any word into the search box which is not present in tree then I am displaying "Nothing To Display." instead of tree. means if tree is displayed in any div then on the search error I am displaying error message in the same div. 
**Now my problem is I want to clear that message on Clear Button and display the same tree again without giving any call to Server**.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide jsfiddle sample? Not sure if I understood your question ....

You can store your json in javascript variable and then use it after clear.